# Switching back and forth between forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

**Topic 1: Switching to another form from the project startup form**

I use the following code that calls an instance of my form for payment (`frmPayment`) from my startup form (`frmMainMenu`) using a click event:

```
Private Sub btnPayment_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPayment.Click, PaymentToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim frmPaymentX As New frmPayment() 'declare payment form
        Me.Visible = False
        frmPaymentX.ShowDialog() 
End Sub
```

Should I use something other than `Me.Visible = False` in handling my startup form (`frmMainMenu`) during my form switch?

**Topic 2: Switching back to the startup form**

Likewise, I use the following code to return to my startup form (`frmMainMenu`) from my form for payment (`frmPayment`):

```
Private Sub btnMainMenu_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles btnMainMenu.Click
        frmMainMenu.Show()
        Me.Close()
End Sub
```

1. Should I directly call my startup form (`frmMainMenu`) as I am doing in my example or should I be calling an instance of my starup form (`frmMainMenu`)?
2. I believe that I should use `show()` and not `showdialog()` for this.  Is this correct?
3. Should I use something other than `Me.Close()`?

Comment: The best practice is the one that works.  What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think you need to clarify why you are wanting to show the payment form and hide the main form. In most applications, when you want to show a dialog of some description, you would show it modally (using `dialog.ShowDialog()`) so that it appears over the top of your current form and prevents the user from interacting with the other form until the opened dialog is closed.

Secondly, if you are wanting your current main form and payment dialog as two screens as opposed to a form and a dialog, then you may be better off creating some shell form that can contain a `UserControl`. You can then build the main form and payment form as two `UserControl`'s and simply switch which is being displayed on your window.

Answer (score 1):

The hiding thing strikes me as a little bit odd.  Generally one doesn't care about hiding the main form.  If the intent is to switch between "pages" in the app, a tab pane or wizard-style setup might be a better idea.

As for your existing code (should you keep it), in the main form, i'd recommend

```vb
Private Sub btnPayment_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles btnPayment.Click, PaymentToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' use `Using` here to ensure the subform is disposed when we're done.
    ' `Close` doesn't dispose forms shown via `ShowDialog`.
    Using frmPaymentX As New frmPayment() 'declare payment form
        Me.Hide()  ' works like `Me.Visible = False`,but more OOPish IMO
        frmPaymentX.ShowDialog()
        Me.Show()  ' duh
    End Using
End Sub
```

In the subform...

```vb
Private Sub btnMainMenu_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles btnMainMenu.Click
    ' (don't worry about controlling the main form here; it'll take care of itself)
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Note, all this is assuming that the subform is indeed a subform (and that the first *aka* 'main' form should control things).  If the two are logically independent and equally in control, then tabs or a wizard would probably be better, depending on which one fits (which only you would know, since we don't have the UI in hand).